# Multivariate calculus question involving chain rule

Tags: multivariable-calculus

[image]

For the first part, I calculated the partials $x_t,x_s,y_t,y_s$ and it seems to create a complicated set of equations that I believe can be solved with linear algebra and subsituting original relations between $x,y$ and $s,t$.  But is there a neater way I'm missing?

Comment: You could use the property that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial s} = \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}$ and likewise for $t$

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst Yes but after you do that its still difficult to find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}$ in terms of $s,t$.

Comment: I don't see how could you use linear algebra - the systems of equations are nonlinear and therefore the coordinate vector of solution with respect to your basis does not exist.

Comment: @ShellRox Well I mean you can find $\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}$ in terms of $x,y,s,t$, but you may be right - it could be almost impossible to use original equations to get it in terms of $s,t$ only.  Do you know an approach?  I will try again later.

Comment: I think you imply substitution - which seems like the most straightforward solution, but not necessarily the neatest (altough I can't think of such approach yet). I assume you already tried isolating $x^2$, $x$, $y$ and plugging them in $z$?

Comment: @ShellRox Because of the squares it doesn't turn out nicely either.  Anyway may have just misinterpreted as it doesn't say to give $\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}$ in terms of $s,t$ only, although that what I thought is implied by these sort of questions.

Comment: It certainly does not, otherwise they would not ask you to evaluate expressions with $x$ and $y$ being specified. I've calculated partial derivatives of $z$ in terms of $s, t, x, y$ and although the expressions are not elegant, they seem to be fit for evaluation task.

Comment: @ShellRox One last clarification needed.  Based on the relations between $x,y,s,t$ should it be possible to express $\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}$ in terms of $s,t$ only?  I think this may be related to inverse function theorem or something, but have not learned it yet.

Comment: You are probably referring to implicit function theorem, as inverse function theorem is obviously based on creating a condition in which a function is invertible for the neighborhood of some point in its domain. As for implicit function theorem, I think you might be correct, since they are asking you to treat $x$ and $y$ as implicit functions of $s$ and $t$, maybe you can try implicitly differentiating it $z$ with that knowledge, regardless of what might yield, it definitely won't be elegant.

Comment: Sounds like you’ve got the right approach in the first place. You end up with two pairs of linear equations in the partial derivatives of $x$ and $y$ at $s=1$, $t=5$, which look quite straightforward to solve.